# JPA Specification with null parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, specifications

I have created JPA Specification like

```
public class CarFilterSpecs {
  public static Specification<Car> carStatusIn(Collection<String> carStatus) {
    return (root, query, builder) ->
            CollectionUtils.isEmpty(carStatus)
                    ? builder.conjunction()
                    : carStatus.contains(-1)
                    ? builder.isNull(root.get("carStatus").get("id"))
                    : root.get("carStatus").get("id").in(carStatus);
  }

  public static Specification<Car> carVisibilityStatusIn(Collection<String> 
    carVisibilityStatus) {
    return (root, query, builder) ->
        CollectionUtils.isEmpty(carVisibilityStatus)
            ? builder.conjunction()
            : carVisibilityStatus.contains(-1)
            ? builder.isNull(root.get("carVisibilityStatus"))
            : root.get("carVisibilityStatus").in(carVisibilityStatus);
  }
}
```

and models looks like

```
public class Status {
  String id;
  String name;
}

public class Car {
  String id;
  Status status;
  ...
}
```

and I am consuming the spec like

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;

Specification<Car> specs = Specification.where(CarSpecs.carStatusIn(status))
     .and(CarSpecs.carVisibilityStatusIn(visibilityStatus));

carRepository.findAll(specs);
```

till here works perfectly but now I am failing to get cars with some status and as well cars with status null(there is a chance of having status null)